# Why I'm keep getting error in the output signal?

Tags: verilog

I write a simple Verilog code for calculating inner product between 2 vectors. I don't understand why, but I get an error in the module's output - red signal. There is probably some problem with the `result` variable. 
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

The code -

```
`resetall
`timescale 1ns/10ps
`include "../hdl/params.v"

module ZCalculationParllel(features_vec, weights_vec, bias, predict);

  // Feature vector in size of |NUMBER_OF_PIXELS| * |PIXEL_PRECISION| 
  input [(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS * `PIXEL_PRECISION) - 1 : 0] features_vec;

  // Weights vector in size of |NUMBER_OF_PIXELS| * |WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION| 
  input [(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS * `WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION) - 1 : 0] weights_vec;

  // Bias vector in size |WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION|
  input [`WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION - 1 : 0] bias;

   // The output value for prediction
  //output predict; in case we want return one bit represent prediction
  output [(2 * `PIXEL_PRECISION + $bits(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS)) - 1 : 0] predict;

  // Accomulator array for saving the multiplication result before the adders
  wire [`PIXEL_PRECISION_PLUS_WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION - 1 : 0] multiplications [0 : `NUMBER_OF_PIXELS - 1];

  wire [(2 * `PIXEL_PRECISION + $bits(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS)) - 1 : 0] result;

  genvar k;
  generate
        for (k = 0; k < `NUMBER_OF_PIXELS; k = k + 1)
         begin: elementMul
           assign multiplications[k] = features_vec[(k + 1) * `PIXEL_PRECISION - 1 -: `PIXEL_PRECISION] * weights_vec[(k + 1) * `WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION - 1 -: `WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION];
        end
    endgenerate

  assign result = 2;
  genvar i;
  generate
        for (i = 0; i < `NUMBER_OF_PIXELS; i = i + 1)
         begin: elementAdd
           assign result = result + multiplications[i];
         end
    endgenerate

  assign predict = result;

endmodule
```

The test -

```
`resetall
`timescale 1ns/10ps
`include "../hdl/ZCalculationParllel.v"
`include "../hdl/params.v"


module ZCalculationParllel_tb ;
  reg [(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS * `PIXEL_PRECISION) - 1 : 0] features;
  reg [(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS * `WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION) - 1 : 0] weights;
  reg [`WEIGHT_BIAS_PRECISION - 1 : 0] b;

  wire [(2 * `PIXEL_PRECISION + $bits(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS)) - 1 : 0] ans;

  ZCalculationParllel z ( 
    .features_vec(features), 
    .weights_vec(weights),
    .bias(b), 
    .predict(ans) 
    );

  initial
    begin
      b = 8'b00000010;

      features[7:0] = 8'b00000010;
      features[15:8] = 8'b00000001;
      features[24:16] = 8'b00000010;

      weights[7:0] = 8'b00000010;
      weights[15:8] = 8'b00000001;
      weights[24:16] = 8'b00000010;

    end 

endmodule
```

Comment: What should I do?  I have to put ```assign``` in the loop...

Comment: I need to sum up all the values that I have in ```multiplications```

Answer (score 0):

`assign` are applied concurrency, not sequentially. Xs will result if any of the assignments are conflicting.

Replace your `result` related code with something like the following:

```
reg [(2 * `PIXEL_PRECISION + $bits(`NUMBER_OF_PIXELS)) - 1 : 0] result;
integer i;
always @* begin
  result = 2;
  for (i = 0; i < `NUMBER_OF_PIXELS; i = i + 1) begin
    result = result + multiplications[i];
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't valid Verilog - the `@*` expands into the equivalent sensitivity list, which includes an array name, which isn't legal. There's also the issue that the process is sensitive to `result`. `always_comb` will handle the array, but the OP's code is clearly old-style plain Verilog (apart from the `$bits`).

Comment: `$bits` is SystemVerilog, but it is something from the OP's original code; something I overlooked. Excluding `$bits`, my example code simulates and synthesizes correctly on EDAplayground (tools constrained to Verilog-2001 features). Icarus did give a warning, but it ran as expected.

Comment: there was an old thread on this years ago in c.l.v, but Google has messed up the usenet search so badly that I can't find it now. My recollection is that Steven Sharp said it shouldn't work but probably would, and someone else had tried it on one or two synthesisers and it didn't work.